# How do I request android runtime permissions the way like in image below?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I found an .apk file and laucnhed on emulator. On start it requests permissions via dialog I have never seen before. I want to create same dialog in my app but I can't find the way dialog below is implemented. I have read many questions on SO and explored some docs but that wasn't I'm looking for. Could you help me to implement request permissions dialog like on the picture?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is [permission screen for legacy apps](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#user-permission-legacy-apps) that was added in android 10:

> If your app targets Android 5.1 (API level 22) or lower, users see a
> permissions screen when using your app on a device that runs Android
> 10 or higher for the first time, as shown in Figure 1. This screen
> gives users the opportunity to revoke access to permissions that the
> system previously granted to your app at install time.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that's exactly what I'm loooking for