# Permission during install time

Tags: android

[Image showing what permission does the app allowed when installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL2qX.png)

Hi there,

I happen to find a sample app that can show the following "Choose what to allowed MainActivity to access", I want to implement it on the other app I am developing. On the other app I am developing, I already have the following permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

However, it does not show like the screenshots which I presented above.

Comment: Might want to research about runtime permissions. Those are different compared to one in the Manifest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I request android runtime permissions the way like in image below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425107/how-do-i-request-android-runtime-permissions-the-way-like-in-image-below)

Comment: adb: failed to install photogallery.apk: Failure [-26: Package com.alienpants.leafpicrevived.debug new target SDK 17 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 28 does.]


Ok, if I downgrade the targetSDK version and I install here is what it does